# Karate API testing - unique value

Tags: java, api, karate, junit5

I was wondering if anyone knows this karate problem I have.

```
  Scenario: a user can create his profile
    Given path '/signup'
    And request { "username":"#(username)", "password":"#(password)" }
    When method POST
    Then status 200
```

the `username` has to have a unique value to get a 200 response. In this case it runs once but for obvious reasons doesn't run again.

Is there a way to hypothetically run the post request or perhaps use a dummy value?

Comment: there's something called `karate.callSingle()` - please search for it and read the docs

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried Postman? It's a program for testing APIs.

Comment: Good idea, I use that aswell, but this is more for the automated production side. It made me think about searching how this problem is solved in postman and they use faker.

[faker](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59893485/2339572).